# angular routing parameters 'state' does not exist in type 'NavigationExtras

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I want to pass parameters to another page, this way:

```
const navParams:NavigationExtras = {state: {functionalityId:'my id'}};
this.router.navigate(['processes'], navParams);
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
Type '{ state: { functionalityId: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'NavigationExtras'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'state' does not exist in type 'NavigationExtras'.
```

I've also tried to pass parameters directly inside navigate:

```
this.router.navigate(['processes'], {functionalityId:'my id'});
```

but I have the (almost) same error:

```
Argument of type '{ functionalityId: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NavigationExtras'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'functionalityId' does not exist in type 'NavigationExtras'
```

Comment: Why queryParams? I want to use `state?: {
    [k: string]: any;
}` as the documentation of NavigationExtras suggests. [link](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#state) . I don't want queryparams, I want to pass data to my processes page

Comment: It works fine for me! how looks your routpath?

Comment: @Taher Hi, in my app.routing.ts I have defined  `const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
[...]
   {path: 'processes', component: ProcessesComponent}
];` and the routing works fine without parameters :\

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. You need the end square bracket to be placed towards the end of the line, like this: `this.router.navigate(['processes', { functionalityId: 'my id' }])`